# something by oneself

Tags: meaning

> ‘The French woman that knew him and owed all her losses to him; the Indian that picked him up, cut and muddy on the street, and played dice with him; they neither of ‘em doubted that Talleyrand was something **by himself**—appearances notwithstanding.’
>       ‘And was he something **by himself**?’ asked Una.
>      Pharaoh began to laugh, but stopped. ‘The way I look at it,’he said, ‘Talleyrand was one of just three men in this world who are **quite by themselves**. Big Hand I put first, because I’ve seen him.’
>      ‘Ay,’ said Puck. ‘I’m sorry we lost him out of Old England. Who d’you put second?’
>      ‘Talleyrand: maybe because I’ve seen him too,’ said Pharaoh.
>      ‘Who’s third?’said Puck.
>      ‘Boney--even though I’ve seen him.’
>       ‘Whew!’ said Puck. ‘Every man has his own weights and measures, but that’s queer reckoning.’ 
>       ‘Boney?’ said Una. ‘You don’t mean you’ve ever met Napoleon Bonaparte?’

This is from *Rewards and Fairies*, "A Priest in Spite of Himself" by Kipling.
http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

What is the meaning of "something by oneself" ?

I am glad if some one kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

*By himself* here is a metaphorical extension of the ordinary meaning "alone". Pharaoh regards Washington, Talleyrand and Napoleon as set apart from all other people, not physically but 'categorically': each of them is so extraordinary and so different from other people that he is "by himself" in a class with no other members.

Comment: a more common, modern usage is to say "he was in a class by himself" .. meaning the same thing